# Update positions in javascript object on sortable change

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

So I have a sortable list. I want to keep the positions of the items in the list that the user interacted with in an object. I use a custom id to identify the items in the list, along with the position they were dropped at. The problem is that, if I drag and drop an item in a position followed by items previously dropped there, all of the positions of the following items change by 1 position.

```
async function makeSortable()
{
  sortableList = $("#itemlist");
  $(sortableList).sortable({
    stop: function(event, ui)
    {
      var order = new Object();
      order.id = ui.item.attr("id").substr(3);
      order.position = ui.item.index();
      console.log(order);
      temp['items'].push(order);
    }
  });
}
```

The reason I'm using an object is because I want to upload the object as a json in a database on beforeunload event (so I need a single object after all list changes).

For example, I move the elements 3,4,5 in positions 0,1,2 respectively and I get this object:

```
{"items":[{"id":"3","position":0},{"id":"4","position":1},{"id":"5","position":2}]}
```

Now, if I drag element 8 in position 1, I get this:

```
{"items":[{"id":"3","position":0},{"id":"4","position":1},{"id":"5","position":2},{"id":"8","position":1}]}
```

I need the positions of elements with id 4 and 5 to indicate positions 2 and 3, respectively, as per the updated list. So my question is, how do I detect this change? I need to mention that I need to retain only the positions of the elements the user interacted with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an easier way to save the specific positions of the items the user interacted with. Simply serialize the order, save into an array which items have been dragged by the user, then compare the results.

```
async function makeSortable()
{
  sortableList = $("#itemlist");
  $(sortableList).sortable({
    update: function(event, ui)
    {
      if (temp && !temp.includes(ui.item.attr("id")))
      {
        temp.push(ui.item.attr("id"));
      }
      var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: is there a way to do this with javascript?